# how to store images  in database

Tags: android, database, image

how to store multiple images in sdcard from internet and store the path in database?   can For multiple images, how should i do?  Till now what i did is..

Table Create Query is Below:

```
"create table table1 (_id integer primary key autoincrement, " 
                  + "title text not null, definition text not null, image BLOB not null);";
```

but for storing one value i have inserted as

```
        bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
        bm = Loadmage(image_URL, bmOptions);

        mImageV.setImageBitmap(bm);


      extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

        OutputStream outStream = null;
           File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "er.PNG");
           try{
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
           }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

So for all the title the same image is showing...I want to display different images for different titles..

Comment: Is there a problem with storing one path per record in the database? Perhaps you need some more detail in the question, such as what your db table looks like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the name of the image as the name at server.
You have to just concat the image name with the directory

**for example**

Suppose you have image name `rose.jpg`
and if you want to save it on SD card then

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/backup/" + rose.jpg);
```

and then you can store path of file name like

```
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
```